# como fazer upload de arquivosem python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

qual método da biblioteca request ou urllib.request eu uso para fazer uploads de arquivo?(Exemplo:fazer uploads de fotos no drive automaticamente,ou no em redes socias automaticamente ou até mesmo o upload de vídeos no youtube)

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla. Mas vai uma dica: Procure a documentação das APIs. O YouTube tem uma API para upload de vídeo, tal qual Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive etc.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente você usaria o `requests.post` - no entanto, essa é a parte mais fácil.

A questão é que essas páginas em geral não tem simplesmente um formulário HTML, com um campo do tipo `<input type="file" ...>` - se fosse esse o caso, seria só uma questão de passar o parâmetro `files=` na chamada ao requests.post - e ele o requests mesmo se encarrega de setar os cabeçalhos http corretamente, (O envio de arquivos requer que o content-type seja `multipart/form-data`, por exemplo).

.

Então, se você tiver uma página que é o destino de um formulário HTTP, e que tenha um ou mais campos `input` para receber arquivos, basta fazer uma chamada como:

```
requests.post("http://pagina.de.envio.com", files={"foto": open("meuarquivo.png", "rb")})
```

(nesse caso, assumindo que o `name` do campo `input` do formulário seja a palavra `foto`).  Você pode enviar mais informações sobre o arquivo, como seu nome, mimetype, etc - e enviar outros dados do mesmo formulário passando o parâmetro `data=` na chamada do  `post`, como se faz normalmente. A documentação (que infelizmente tem só alguns exemplos, não a descrição exata) está em: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Agora - mesmo para um site simples, com um formulário em "web 1.0", vocẽ tem que estar logado, em geral - isso exige que você use a biblioteca requests para criar uma `session`, enviando em postagens anteriores o login e a  senha, e aí você manda o `post` a partir dessa `session`, não direto o  `requests.post`

## a má notícia

é que o método acima só funciona pra páginas simples, em que você tem um formulário direto para upload de imagens. Os sites que você citou - google-drive e redes sociais, usam mecanismos bem mais complexos para fazer upload de imagens, e dificilmente você vai conseguir algo enviando um post como se fosse um formulário preenchido, que na verdade, emula o que um navegador faz quando envia um formulário.  A interface Web de upload desses sites usa uma porção de código (javascript, no front-end) personalizado e em geral vai fazer requisições bem específicas para enviar os dados do arquivo em si.

Fazer a engenharia reversa de como um arquivo é enviado pela interface nesses sites seria uma tarefa gigante. Por outro lado, vários desses sites -  o google-drive especificamente, apresentam uma API para interação programática. Ou seja: você não vai usar a `requests` do Python para interagir com o site como se fosse um navegador vendo o conteúdo em HTML - e sim, vai chamar endereços específicos do site, com o conteúdo bem documentado, em geral codificado como JSON para fazer tarefas como subir arquivos ou outras interações. (Nesses casos, em vez de chamar o `requests.post` com o parâmetro `file=`, você vai chamar um método específico para subir imagens ou arquivos da biblioteca da API)

Em geral os sites que oferecem uma API oferecem também, além da documentação, um pacote de Python que você vai usar - no lugar do requests - para interagir com o site. E continuando a má notícia: para poder usar a API, e usar essa biblioteca da API, cada site desses funciona de um jeito - você vai ter que, para cada site, estudar a documentação, aprender a gerar uma chave, instalar a biblioteca de API, e aprender a usa-la -

Para cada site comece fazendo uma busca do tipo: "google drive api file upload tutorial", "facebook api photo upload tutorial" -  e esteja preparado para uma longa, mas empolgante, jornada.

Por exemplo, para o google drive, depois de instalar a biblioteca da API,  configurar uma chave de acesso para o seu app, e fazer os imports necessários, o código para subir um arquivo é:

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

(exemplo extraído de https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple , a documentação do setup da API para Python está em:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python )

O código é até simples - mas a documentação do passo a passo pode ser complicadinha. E isso é para cada site.